# Tabulator - formatting print and PDF output

Tags: pdf, printing, styling, tabulator

I am a relatively new user of Tabulator so please forgive me if I am asking anything that, perhaps, should be obvious.

I have a Tabulator report that I am able to print and create as a PDF, but the report's formatting (as shown on the screen) is not used in either output.

For printing I have used printAsHtml and printStyled=true, but this doesn't produce a printout that matches what is on the screen. I have formatted number fields (with comma separators) and these are showing correctly, but the number columns should be right-aligned but all of the columns appear as left-aligned.

I am also using Tree View where the tree rows are coloured differently to the main table, but when I print the report with a tree open it colours the whole table with the tree colours and not just the tree.

For the PDF none of the Tabulator formatting is being used. I've looked for anything similar to the printStyled option, but I can't see anything. I've also looked at the autoTable option, but I am struggling to find what to use.

I want to format the print and PDF outputs so that they look as close to the screen representation as possible.

Is there anywhere I could look that would provide examples of how to achieve the above? The Tabulator documentation is very good, but the provided examples don't appear to explain what I am trying to do.

Perhaps there are there CSS classes that I am missing or even mis-using? I have tried including .tabulator-print-table in my CSS, but I am probably not using it correctly. I also couldn't find anything equivalent for producing PDFs. Some examples would help immensely.

Thank you in advance for any advice or assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting is deliberately not included in these, below i will outline why:

##### Downloaders

Downloaded files do not contain formatted data, only the raw data, this is because a lot of the formatters create visual elements *(progress bar, star formatter etc)* that cannot be replicated sensibly in downloaded files.

If you want to change the format of data in the download you will need to use an accessor, the `accessorDownload` option is the one you want to use in this case. The accessors transform the data as it is leaving the table.

For instance we could create an accessor that prepended "Mr " to the front of every name in a column:

```js
var mrAccessor= function(value, data, type, params, column, row){
    return "Mr " + value;
}
```

Assign it to a columns definition:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", accessorDownload:mrAccessor}
```

##### Printing

Printing also does not include the formatters, this is because when you print a Tabulator table, the whole table is actually rebuilt as a standard HTML table, which allows the printer to work out how to layout everything across multiple pages with column headers etc. The downside of this is that it is only loosely styled like a Tabulator and so formatted contents generated inside Tabulator cells will likely break when added to a normal `td` element.

For this reason there is also a `accessorPrint` option that works in the same way as the download accessor but for printing.

If you want to use the same accessor for both occasions, you can assign the function once to the `accessor` option and it will be applied in both instances.

Checkout the [Accessor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/mutators#accessors) for full details.

Comment: Hi, Oli, thank you for your reply, it is very helpful. I kind of thought that would be the case. I will take a closer look at the Accessors. It does look as though they will do what I would like. I will also need to take a look at updating my code to version 5.1, I'm currently on 4.9. Hopefully I won't find that too arduous! Thank you once again for your support it is much appreciated.

Comment: The accessors will work in 4.9 so you should be all good there. When you are upgrading, checkout the [Upgrade Guide](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.0/upgrade) for a full breakdown of all the changes

Answer (score 0):

Use print formatter in the row definition. For example to print color of a cell use the Tabulator color formatter but then specify formatterPrint to render the color as div border which will get printed.

```
      {title: "Color", field: "color1", formatter:"color", minWidth:10,
                formatterPrint:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
                   return "<div style='padding: 0px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 12px solid "+cell.getValue()+"; background-color:" +cell.getValue()+ " '>   </div>"; 
                },
      },
```

Normal vview:

[image]

Printable view:
[image]

See more here:
https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/format#format-export